# Java - Displaying a static fileChooser panel and a dynamic checkbox panel in a single gui

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, dynamic, event-dispatch-thread

I'm working on a college project to allow a user select a csv file via a file chooser in a GUI and then display a checkbox for each column of the file.

I have the back end code written to handle any number of columns but the problem I'm having is displaying the checkboxes. The way I approached this was to put the file chooser in one panel and the checkboxes in a second with the intention of adding the second panel, setting it visible, from a actionListener method, once the file had been read.

However without the array of checkbox names filled when the GUI is first setup I'm unable to display the checkboxes.

I've since tried using both tabbed layout [tabbed layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) and [card layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and read up on wizard layout, but from what ive seen, these all had their components initalised and the action listeners were simply setting them visible/invisible?

At this stage Im beginning to wonder is it even possible to do this in a single gui or how could I approach the problem with two GUI's.

I've only been using java for 3months and any pointers in the right direction would be a huge help, 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider

- Reading the CSV file in a SwingWorker's doInBackground method so as not to freeze the event thread
- You can have the GUI get notified when the SwingWorker is done by adding a PropertyChangeListener to the SwingWorker, and checking if the PropertyChangeEvent's propertyName is "state" and its newValue is SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE.
- Once you get your column names, you can dynamically create your JCheckBoxes and add them to a JPanel that uses GridLayout. There's no restriction from creating components dynamically in Swing.
- Then display that JPanel in the GUI either via a CardLayout, or by adding it to a displayed container, or by showing it in a dialog window such as a JDialog or JOptionPane. Again, there's no restriction from doing this in Swing.
- Be sure to `revalidate()` and `repaint()` any container that is changed, or calling `pack()` on the JFrame if you need to resize it (not recommended if at all possible).

Comment: I think this sounds like what I need, I'll only be able to read the file once the user has selected it via the fileChooser so would I call the doInBackground method from the actionListener on the fileChooser? edit - this is the first GUI I've built that hasnt all been run in the "main" thread

Comment: @rafferb: You'd want to read up on use of SwingWorkers (check [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)). You never call the `doInBackground()` method. You call its `execute()` method similar to how you almost never call a Thread or Runnable's `run()` method but rather call the Thread's `start()` method.

Comment: Thanks for that, hopefully I'll get it sorted with that!

Answer (score 2):

```
I'm working on a college project to allow a user select a csv file via a 
file chooser in a GUI and then display a checkbox for each column of the file.

I have the back end code written to handle any number of columns but the 
problem I'm having is displaying the checkboxes.
```

`cvs file` represents table structures, use [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) rather than bothering with placing tons of `JComponents` to the GUI, in the `JTable` represent `JCheckBox` only `Boolean` value

Comment: @rafferb: this suggestion is much better than mine. 1+

Comment: Thanks, maybe I've got it wrong but a table would seem to display the data in the file? The reason I was using checkboxes is that the rest of the program will output a graph, in a separate gui, of each of the selected columns and the columns can have hundreds of row values!